How to integrate by loopback4 backend with Angular frontend?
I am new to loopback4 and I'm working on integrating loopback4 backend with Angular frontend. Is there any proper documentation on how to do it?
I tried searching on different forums but didn't get any result. Please help me find any resources for integrating loopback4 backend with Angular frontend.

I don't know about loopack4 but I think that is the same than another API, you should be running at time the loopback4 and your angular app (in different ports)

Here is our angular project that we use to connect with loopback
This is what we follow
https://github.com/sourcefuse/angular-boilerplate
